# OutputFormatter XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter asp.net core not reaching child of child

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My .NET Core API test project contains data that should be returned in XML format, so I installed and setup `XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter` in the Startup class,

```
services.AddMvc(setupAction => 
            {
                setupAction.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
                setupAction.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter()); 
            });
```

and once I set the Accept Header in Postman to `application/xml` value, the data gets returned as XML, but this can only reach the parent and first child, after that, the results are standard JSON format.
[Parent with grandchild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mORnI.png)

[Parent with first child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtqFU.png)

Authors Controller code:

```
namespace Lib.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/authors/{authorId}/books")]
    public class BooksController : Controller
    {
        private ILibraryRepository _libraryRepository;

        public BooksController(ILibraryRepository libraryRepository)
        {
            _libraryRepository = libraryRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult GetBooksForAuthor(Guid authorId)
        {
            if (!_libraryRepository.AuthorExists(authorId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var booksForAuthorFromRepo = _libraryRepository.GetBooksForAuthor(authorId);

            var booksForAuthor = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BookDto>>(booksForAuthorFromRepo);

            return Ok(booksForAuthor);
        }
        
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetBookForAuthor(Guid authorId, Guid Id)
        {
            if (!_libraryRepository.AuthorExists(authorId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var bookForAuthorFromRepo = _libraryRepository.GetBookForAuthor(authorId, Id);
            if (bookForAuthorFromRepo == null)
            {
                return NotFound("The book does not exist");
            }
            var bookForAuthor = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BookDto>(bookForAuthorFromRepo);
            return new JsonResult(bookForAuthor);
        }
    }
}
```

Books Controller code:

```
namespace Lib.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/authors/{authorId}/books")]
    public class BooksController : Controller
    {
        private ILibraryRepository _libraryRepository;

        public BooksController(ILibraryRepository libraryRepository)
        {
            _libraryRepository = libraryRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult GetBooksForAuthor(Guid authorId)
        {
            if (!_libraryRepository.AuthorExists(authorId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var booksForAuthorFromRepo = _libraryRepository.GetBooksForAuthor(authorId);

            var booksForAuthor = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BookDto>>(booksForAuthorFromRepo);

            return Ok(booksForAuthor);
        }
        
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetBookForAuthor(Guid authorId, Guid Id)
        {
            if (!_libraryRepository.AuthorExists(authorId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var bookForAuthorFromRepo = _libraryRepository.GetBookForAuthor(authorId, Id);
            if (bookForAuthorFromRepo == null)
            {
                return NotFound("The book does not exist");
            }
            var bookForAuthor = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BookDto>(bookForAuthorFromRepo);
            return new JsonResult(bookForAuthor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the *relevant* code - the controllers, actions and the code that creates and returns the response data. The screenshots don't show anything related to the question - they show two different requests, not a single XML document with children.

Comment: What is the *raw* response?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is the raw response  

`{"id":"c7ba6add-09c4-45f8-8dd0-eaca221e5d93","title":"The Shining","description":"The Shining is a horror novel by American author Stephen King. Published in 1977, it is King\u0027s third published novel and first hardback bestseller: the success of the book firmly established King as a preeminent author in the horror genre. ","authorId":"25320c5e-f58a-4b1f-b63a-8ee07a840bdf"}`

Comment: `return new JsonResult` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
Thanks, changing the return result to `return Ok` solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the return type from JsonResult() to Ok() solved the issue.
Thanks to @PanagiotisKanavos